# How to calculate the mean of specific rows in R

Tags: r, mean

I have a dataset containing wind direction ("WD") data on specific days, for the years 1996-2014. I would like to calculate the mean WD value for each day, but there are multiple values for one particular day because this data is collected hourly.

I am not sure how I can specify that I want the mean WD values for rows with specific dates, like the mean value for all rows that contain Year=1996, Month=08, Day=02.

An example of my dataset is like the following:

| Year | Month | Day | Hour | WD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1996 | 08 | 02 | 01 | 250 |
| :---- | :-----: | :---: | :----: | ----: |
| 1996 | 08 | 02 | 02 | 284 |
| :---- | :-----: | :---: | :----: | ----: |
| 1996 | 08 | 02 | 03 | 143 |
| :---- | :-----: | :---: | :----: | ----: |
| 1996 | 08 | 02 | 04 | 310 |
| :---- | :-----: | :---: | :----: | ----: |
| 1996 | 08 | 02 | 05 | 245 |

Thank you in advance for your consideration!

I don't know of any code, other than the mean() function, to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Change your question Which db , is it a db query you want or post processing in another language from a result set?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is with `dplyr`. Suppose your dataframe is named `df` then one can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Year, Month, Day) %>% summarize(WD_mean = mean(WD))
```

That will return the mean for each date.